# How to use loops in Java

Tags: java, loops, selection

**I need help on how to use for-loops in Java**

**This is an assignment for class, so I'd rather just be pointed in the right direction instead of given an answer.**

"List of valid seven dwarfs: Sleepy, Bashful, Doc, Sneezy, Happy, Grumpy, Dopey
Pool of random characters, non-valid Dwarfs:  Lion-O, Cheetara, Panthro, Tigra, Snarf, Donald Duck, Mickey Mouse, Minnie Mouse, Goofy, Heathcliff, Huey, Dewey, Louie, Scrooge McDuck,

Declare these variables:

```
int counter = 7;
boolean firstSelection = false;
boolean secondSelection = false;
boolean thirdSelection = false;
boolean fourthSelection = false;
boolean fiveSelection = false;
boolean sixSelection = false;
boolean sevenSelection = false;
```

Print a list of three choices to the console.  Ask the user to pick the correct dwarf of the three choices.
The list of three choices will include two names from the random characters list and one name from the seven dwarfs.
You will create a switch statement to handle the choice selection
When the wrong case is selected then decrement the int variable called counter and print to the console “wrong selection”
When the correct case is selected then change the corresponding boolean variable to true (ie.. firstSelection, secondSelection, etc) and print to the console “Hi Ho, you picked the correct one”
The default case will print a statement to the console “invalid selection”
Create a loop that will perform this seven times until you covered all seven dwarfs.

- Use a for loop
- Recreate the loop again using a do-while loop
- Recreate the loop again using a while loop
  At the end, create an if-else statement.  This statement will have short circuit &&’s that will test all of the Boolean variables.  If true, print a statement to the console “You earned a gold star!”.  Else, print a statement to the console “You did not get all correct”. "

I completed the previous assignment, which was just this specification without the loops, with no problem. However I really don't understand how the professor wants us to integrate the loops into the problem. The only thing I can think of is that he wants up to create a loop seven times that somehow asks about a different dwarf each of the seven times. Is that even possible? Can you change the content of the loops as you are running through it? I feel like I am just not even thinking about this correctly.

Here is my code from the previous assignment, sans loops:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SevenDwarfs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 7;
        boolean firstSelection = false;
        boolean secondSelection = false;
        boolean thirdSelection = false;
        boolean fourthSelection = false;
        boolean fiveSelection = false;
        boolean sixSelection = false;
        boolean sevenSelection = false;

        System.out
                .println("Which of the following is one of the seven drawfs?");
        System.out.println("1 Sleepy");
        System.out.println("2 Lion-O");
        System.out.println("3 Cheetara");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Hi Ho, you picked the correct one");
            firstSelection = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        }

        System.out
                .println("Which of the following is one of the seven drawfs?");
        System.out.println("1 Panthro");
        System.out.println("2 Bashful");
        System.out.println("3 Tigra");

        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice2 = input2.nextInt();
        switch (choice2) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Hi Ho, you picked the correct one");
            secondSelection = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        }

        System.out
                .println("Which of the following is one of the seven drawfs?");
        System.out.println("1 Snaf");
        System.out.println("2 Doc");
        System.out.println("3 Donald Duck");

        Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice3 = input3.nextInt();

        switch (choice3) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Hi Ho, you picked the correct one");
            thirdSelection = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        }

        System.out
                .println("Which of the following is one of the seven drawfs?");
        System.out.println("1 Mickie Mouse");
        System.out.println("2 Sneezy");
        System.out.println("3 Minie Mouse");

        Scanner input4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice4 = input4.nextInt();
        switch (choice4) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Hi Ho, you picked the correct one");
            fourthSelection = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        }

        System.out
                .println("Which of the following is one of the seven drawfs?");
        System.out.println("1 Heathcliff");
        System.out.println("2 Happy");
        System.out.println("3 Goofy");

        Scanner input5 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice5 = input5.nextInt();
        switch (choice5) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Hi Ho, you picked the correct one");
            fiveSelection = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        }

        System.out
                .println("Which of the following is one of the seven drawfs?");
        System.out.println("1 Huey");
        System.out.println("2 Grumpy");
        System.out.println("3 Dewey");

        Scanner input6 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice6 = input6.nextInt();
        switch (choice6) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Hi Ho, you picked the correct one");
            sixSelection = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        }

        System.out
                .println("Which of the following is one of the seven drawfs?");
        System.out.println("1 Scrooge McDuck");
        System.out.println("2 Dopey");
        System.out.println("3 Louie");

        Scanner input7 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice7 = input7.nextInt();
        switch (choice7) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Hi Ho, you picked the correct one");
            sevenSelection = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Wrong selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid selection");
            --counter;
            break;
        }

        if (firstSelection == true && secondSelection == true
                && thirdSelection == true && fourthSelection == true
                && fiveSelection == true && sixSelection == true
                && sevenSelection == true) {
            System.out.println("You earned a gold star!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nYou did not get all correct.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: he asks you to replace switch statements with loops.

Comment: Hi Roman, do you think you could write an example of how to do that?

Comment: @Roman C: I do not think that is the case. Rather, the switch statement should be contained in the for-loop.

Comment: this is a homework assignment I could only give directions and descriptions

Comment: @Kim Hansson: From a few email exchanges, I was under the impression that the switch was supposed to stay but be inside a loop, just have no idea how to do that with out have the same questions be repeated over and over.

Comment: Try using multiple switch statements.  One that controls the question that is asked, and another that takes care of the user input.  Put those inside your loop.

Comment: this is what is not expected, the purpose of the loops to iterate some data, so switch is not required

Comment: i got his idea was to lead you make changes if you stuck on switches, after loops are created then switches needs to replace

Comment: keep in mind (and in memory forever) in the code if you see repeating statements (like `case`) that is possible candidate to put in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you realized you might be thinking about the concept incorrectly and asked for help is a good thing.

Read the following to get familiar with loops in Java.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

To answer your question, yes, you can change the content of a loop as you run it.  That's what variables are for.  You can modify their values as your program runs.  Look at this sample.  The variable i increments with every iteration of the loop.  The variable outsideLoop also changes inside the loop.  Play with this and you'll start to understand.

```
class ForDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int outsideLoop = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            outsideLoop += i;
            System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
        }
        System.out.println("Outside loop is: " + outsideLoop);
    }
}
```

You've got a good starting point for the process of printing the selection, getting user input, and validating user input.  Repeat that chunk (in a loop) 7 times.